# How to use third party Java library in existing web application

Tags: java, web, cryptography, bouncycastle

I have a third party library (Bouncy Castle) and I've developed app in pure Java that signs some message, i.e. calculates the hash of that message.
There is also a web page (html + javascript)

I need use the Java library (code that I have) from the web page. To be more specific:

- user enters information about himself
- clicks button
- a modal form for choosing key file appears
- user chooses key file
- web page calculates hash of the data by means of java library

What is the best (right) way of doing this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm sorry but this is a too broad question according to this site rules. You should read [ask] to know what questions are accepted or not, and how to ask them. Just to give you some hints, if will be easy to use a Java library from a server side Servlet, and you can submit requests to that servlet from client javascript. But the question is way too broad for me to provide a true answer is SO rules.

Comment: Too broad question indeed. If you have to use any third party java library, then add it as a dependency to a build tool like maven/gradle or add it to the application classpath.

Comment: ok, i try to do some deeper search in topic. Thanks!